# Image pyramid with transparent pixels

Tags: geoserver, gdal, tiles, image-pyramids

I have a GeoTiff image which I wan't to use to build tile pyramid and serve it via geoserver. In most cases it works well but fails to publish a layer if tiled images have NO_DATA (transparent) pixels.

Can I serve images with NO_DATA as pyramid from geoserver? Or I need some workaround?

P.S. I can imagine a workaround to replace transparent values with some color and then make it transparent again by InputTransparentColor coverage parameter (in layer settings)